# LTE拡張ボードの I2C を Arduino で使用するには？

Tags: spresense

以下の様な記載がありますが、Arduinoで使用する場合はどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

> SpresenseではメインボードとLTE拡張ボードにそれぞれI2C接続に使用できる端子が１系統用意されています(LTE拡張ボードはPWM2、PWM3と排他使用になります）。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

Spresense Arduino環境からI2C#1(PWM2,3と共有ピン)を利用できるようにWireライブラリに`Wire1`インスタンスを追加しました。

ピンの対応関係は以下の通りで、I/O電圧は拡張ボード側のジャンパによって3.3V/5Vを切り替え可能です。
PWM2 : I2C#1-SCL
PWM3 : I2C#1-SDA

使用方法は、一般的な Wire ライブラリと同様です。
`Wire.begin()` を `Wire1.begin()` のように置き換えて使用してください。

対応したものを開発("develop")ブランチにアップしています。
https://github.com/SPRESENSE/spresense-arduino-compatible/releases
SPRESENSE beta release (2021/09/11)

開発("develop")ブランチのArduinoパッケージを使用する方法はこちらを参考にしてください。
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_set_up_ja.html#_プレリリース_spresense_arduino_board_package_パッケージのインストール](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_set_up_ja.html#_%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9_spresense_arduino_board_package_%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)

今回の対応は次回のオフィシャルリリースに取り込んで正式サポートする予定です。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
SPRESENSEサポートチーム